# How to disable the picker row - Titanium?

Tags: javascript, android, titanium-mobile

I want to create a date time picker for one mobile app in Titanium Studio (for Android). I need to disable some picker rows like- All Saturdays and Sundays. I am not finding any way to do it, there is no property in Titanium Picker using that I can disable the particular picker row. Is there any other way or any API available for the same?

Comment: Can you show some example code of how you are setting up your code currently?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is even possible in the native Android API, using a DatePicker. However, to achieve what you are asking in Titanium you can:

1. Create a normal picker, where you can specify manually the columns and rows, and then transform the selection to a date value.
2. Create date picker, and watch the 'change' event. If the selected date is on a 'forbidden' date, show an alert and set programatically the picker value to a valid date.